# Getting images from KMZ files

Tags: python, image, path, kml, kmz

I'm trying to take an image out of a KMZ file. I currently have the local path of the kmz and the path of the file inside its respective kml file (relative, not global), and what I need is to get the path to load the file to a database. Is there a way to get it using basic string-type paths?

Answer (score 1):

A KMZ is just Zip archive (with a .kmz extension instead of .zip), so you should be able to unzip it and access all the files with "zipfile" or similar.

Comment: You are right! Thank you, just opened it with zipfile.ZipFile and I was able to access to those files.